# Browser sync Rhino Environment. - Usecase

Tags: javascript, node.js, rhino, browser-sync

1) I have a question regarding browser sync server side code being executed inside [Rhino Environment](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino).

The client for whom I'm working for is giving me browser sync code as a npm packaged code executed using gulp.

2) I have one more question, whether browser sync can be used as a tool to prevent the user's of this app to open multiple tabs of the same website/app that we are developing and create conflicting form changes, since browser sync will always show the same page/state across all tabs in the same browser. Or is it an overkill to implement the same using browser sync?

Answer (score 0):

1) Browser sync is not supported at the moment for Rhino.
2) Using browser sync as a tool to prevent users from making conflicting changes is doable, but it looks like an over kill due to the following reasons.

1. Browser sync applied to a load balanced application becomes another hassle. More load will be spent on this feature alone.
2. The conflicting changes by same user won't be a real possibility anyways.
3. Making the pages to the application in every tab open change at the same time loses the flexibility of doing multiple views of the app at all.

So the solution for question 2) will be to handle form editing states in locally shared area like localstorage. So that all tabs of the web app will be aware of any specific form edit state.